# Why the graphs of non linear functions are curved lines?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

The graph of the linear equation is, as it's name says, a straight line. But why the points of quadratic, cubic, etc, functions are connected by a smooth curve instead of a line? I've heard that the reason is because if we use straight lines to connect the points of a quadratic function, that wouldn't show the true behavior of the function. What does this mean, exactly?

On the other hand, I have read that there exist functions which doesn't have graphs. What are examples of these functions?

Comment: Not sure why this is getting close votes for 'unclear what you're asking'. I think the main question is pretty clear, if rooted in misconception.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say 'the points of the function', I imagine you are considering values at integers, or maybe a few other nice numbers that you plug in. So for $y=x^2$ you would have points $(1,1),$ $(2,4)$, $(3,9),$ $(-1,1)$, $(-2,4)$ , etc... maybe a few others. However, to use same terminology as what you heard, the "true function" has infinitely many points. You could put $(1/2,1/4),$ $(1/4,1/16),$ $(3/4,9/16),$ $(-\sqrt{2},2)$ and all kinds of points down for any $x$ value you can think of and they all have to lie  on the graph of the function.

In fact, there are so many points that need to lie on the graph that they are infinitely close together. Thus there is really no freedom in how you draw the lines 'connecting the points'. The way the graph needs to curve coming out of a point is totally determined by the points infinitely close to it. If you plot points on a dense grid of $x$ values you will see them blend together into a curved shape. Then you can just draw a smooth line through them and it will be curved in the shape of a parabola (or whatever function you're graphing). This is just what a graphing calculator does when it draws the graph of a function. (It might even draw straight lines in between the points, but the points are so close together that your eye can't tell the difference.

Comment: Now I see that the infinite number of points generates the curved line. But what about a linear function? It have infinitely many points, but it isn't a curved line. Why the behaviour is different?

Comment: @JohnFinkelstein A linear function is special in that the points its graph has on it, because of the function rule, happen to lie on a straight line. This is why t's *called* a linear function. Imagine you have, say, $f(x) = 2x$ and you've graphed the points $(1,2)$ and $(2,4)$ and $(3,6).$ You see these all lie on a straight line, but you're skeptical and want to use a denser set of points. So you go to $x=1.5,$ halfway in between the x coords of the first two. For the $y$ value you get $y=3,$ halfway between the $y$ coordinates. It's still on the line! See how this will happen every time?

Comment: Yes! That's a convincing argument. It also shows that it only happens with linear functions. I only want to ask you one more short question. The method of plotting graphs using the points of the function for particular values, does work in all cases? Because I read in the book Calculus of rational functions that it seems to fail for a rational function and that it only can be draw using the "method of transformation". Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is the link if you're interested 
 https://archive.org/stream/CalculusOfRationalFunctionslittleMathematicsLibrary/Shilov-Calculus-of-Rational-Functions-LML#page/n10/mode/1up

Comment: @JohnFinkelstein No, the method of plotting some points is unreliable, although in many cases it can give you a decent idea of what the function 'looks like'. It needs to be combined with some other insights though, and you'll learn techniques in classes on algebra / precalc / calc to get a good picture of the whole thing. Usually this involves spotting points where the function blows up to infinity and analyzing behavior as $x$ gets large or goes into different regions. Perhaps less relevant but see my comment to the other answer for a function for which the very idea of graphing is hopeless.

Answer (score 1):

For your OTHER question:

You want to remember that a graph is a visual *representation* of a function.

For example, let's say my function turned "Bananas" into $3$, and "Apples" into $6$.

Most likely here, I'd represent  my function as a *table*.

Here, you speak of functions that take a subset of $\mathbb R$ (domain) and map it onto another subset of $\mathbb R $ (range).

In this case, say we have a function $f$, then we would *represent* the function on a coordinate plane as all points that are of the form $(x,f(x))$.

If you had a function that took in one number, let's say: time, and gave two outputs, say temperature and humidity: you would need three axes to plot a point on (time, temperature, humidity).

You can still represent this, but not on a coordinate plane, for certain.

Once you have more than three dimensions, it's hard to make a *non-table* visual model.

You sometimes have to introduce representations like vector fields (arrows) and colors, to make the data stick on a $2d$ plane or a $3d$ model.

Comment: True but graph is also a technical term meaning the set of points on the plane that obey the functional relationship. But if we're talking about *drawing* a graph, then certainly there are functions that can't be adequately represented. Dimensionality isn't the only factor. Even in one dimension, a function can be any crazy relationship between real values $x$ and $f(x)$. Most of these won't be drawable in any meaningful way. Say the function that returns the sum of its numerator and denominator in lowest terms if $x$ is rational and its 31st decimal digit if irrational.

Comment: It's an interesting example. So this function seems to consist  of just random points on the plane that don't tell us very much, altought  functions of this type of can be indeed meaningful.